# Select Data Where Data have value below Current Value

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, mariadb, window-functions

I have Data

```
user    indeks_sum    sks_sum    year
2000    76            21         20191
2000    NULL          21         20192 
2012    12            24         20191
2012    NULL           8         20192
2042    21            16         20191
2042    NULL           9         20192
2069    8              2         20191
2069    4              1         20192
```

expected result :

```
user    indeks_sum    sks_sum    year
2000    76            21         20191
2000    76            42         20192 
2012    12            24         20191
2012    12            32         20192
2042    21            16         20191
2042    21            25         20192
2069    8              2         20191
2069    12             3         20192
```

`indeks_sum` and `sks_sum` increased every `year`
i have try

```
select * user,sum(indeks_sum) as indeks_sum, sum(sks_sum) as sks_sum, year
from ips
where year <= year
group by user,year
```

but result still same.
thanks in advance

Comment: `WHERE \`year\` <= year AND indeks_sum IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Your where clause has no effect since year is always less than or equal to itself. I suspect you might benefit from learning about the HAVING clause - and how it differs from the WHERE clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions - if your version of MySQL / MariaDB supports them: this is a good use case for window sums.

```
select
    user,
    sum(indeks_sum) over(partition by user order by year)) indeks_sum,
    sum(sks_sum)    over(partition by user order by year) sks_sum,
    year
from ips
order by user, year
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=9e26b9cbd24b24c458d4fcc469e6b542)**:

```
user | indeks_sum | sks_sum |  year
---: | ---------: | ------: | ----:
2000 |         76 |      21 | 20191
2000 |         76 |      42 | 20192
2012 |         12 |      24 | 20191
2012 |         12 |      32 | 20192
2042 |         21 |      16 | 20191
2042 |         21 |      25 | 20192
2069 |          8 |       2 | 20191
2069 |          4 |       3 | 20192
```

---

In earlier versions, here is one approach using correlated subqueries:

```
select
    i.user,
    (select sum(i1.indeks_sum) from ips i1 where i1.user = i.user and i1.year <= i.year) indeks_sum,
    (select sum(i1.sks_sum)    from ips i1 where i1.user = i.user and i1.year <= i.year) sks_sum,
    i.year
from ips i
order by i.user, i.year
```

For performance, consider an index on `(user, year, indeks_sum)` and another on `(user, year, sks_sum)`.

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5602fda7dd578e276ac89e0760132afd)**

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'over(partition by `user` order by `year`)) `sum_indeks`,
    (sum(' at line 3

Comment: @hooman182: which version of MySQL are you running? Window functions are available in MySQL 8.0 only.

Comment: Server version: 5.7.29 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)  im running on Cpanel mySQL

Comment: @hooman182: OK. I edited my answer with a solution for ealier versions.

Comment: so must make condition on select subqueries. i have a very bad dream about subqueries. its running very slow on my server

Comment: @hooman182: why not upgrade to MySQL 8.0? Otherwise, I added index suggestions to my answer.

Comment: its provided by WHM. so basicly its free version. i only can choose between mariadb or mysql GPL. thanks for answer. its works like a charm.